# Limits to multiple Eloquent relationships ?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a number of different roles, who are all essentially "users" in my laravel app.

I'm having a problem with eloquent relationships where I can easily get one of the relationships, in the context of the user as a car owner, but when I try get another relationship in the context of a (different) user as a maintenance manager, I get this error: `Cannot redeclare class App\Models\User`.

**serviceAgreement model**

```
public function manager()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('carfreak\Models\User','manager_id','id');
    }
```

**Works fine:**

`$managers = $owner->serviceAgreement()->get();`

**produces error**

`$managers = $owner->serviceAgreement()->with('manager')->get();`

I'm thinking the problem lies somewhere in how I've written my relationship - my referring to the `\Models\User`. I've tried to refer to the logged in user, but it (a) doesn't make sense for this application and (b) doesn't work anyway.

`return $this->belongsTo(Auth::User(),'manager_id','id');`

Some pointers please?

Answer (score 0):

That is happen because the `App\Models\User` class is declared at least 2 times. Change

`public function manager()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('carfreak\Models\User','manager_id','id');
    }`

to

```
public function manager()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','manager_id','id');
}
```

You should go fine now.

Hope it helps.